# Get two separate values from MySQL database, do a sum, and update one of the values

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables

I have a MySQL database. This consists of various tables, including 'members' and 'stocks'.

I am creating a 'stock trading game' and want to deduct the amount a stock costs, from the balance a user currently has.

I have the column 'price' within the stocks table and
the column 'balance' within the members table.

When a button is clicked I want the price of a stock to be subtracted from the balance of a member.

If I'm honest, I have no idea on how to do this, but as an attempt here is my code that I have tried, but actually does nothing:

```
if (isset($_POST['user']))
{
    $userselection = sanitizeString($_POST['userselection']);


    if ($userselection == "")
        $error = "Not all fields were entered<br /><br />";
    else
    {
            $stockprice = queryMysql("SELECT price FROM stocks WHERE name='$userselection'");
            $newbalance = ($balance - $stockprice);
            queryMysql("INSERT INTO members VALUES('', '', '', '', '', '', '$newbalance',  )");
            die("<h4>You just bought $userselection</h4><br /><br />");

    }
}
```

schema:
[image]

```
<?php 
include_once 'functions.php';

createTable('members',
            'id INT(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            firstname VARCHAR(100),
            surname varchar(100),
            user varchar(30),
            pass varchar(30),
            email varchar(100),
            balance float(12),
            PRIMARY KEY (id)');


createTable('stocks', 
            'id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            name VARCHAR(16),
            price float(16)');

createTable('profiles',
            'user VARCHAR(16),
            text VARCHAR(4096)');

?>
```

Comment: can you post the schema of the tables?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`?

Comment: @JW웃 I've now uploaded the schema

Comment: @ExplosionPills Do I literally just change it from UPDATE to INSERT?

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE members m join stocks s on s.id = m.stock_id where m.balance = m.balance - s.price`

If you were to post your schema as a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com), I could actually test this query.

Answer (score 0):

In general:

```
UPDATE Members
INNER JOIN Stocks ON Stocks.Name = '<name-of-stock>'
SET balance = balance - Stocks.price * <number-of-stocks>
WHERE Members.ID = <member-id>
```

Use [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to interact with the database. It's safer. Here's an example; you'll need to supply the stock name, number of stocks, and member ID in addition to your database connection info, but you'd need to do all these things even if you aren't using mysqli:

```
$sql = <<< ENDSQL
  UPDATE Members
    INNER JOIN Stocks ON Stocks.Name = ?
    SET balance = balance - Stocks.price * ?
    WHERE Members.ID = ?
ENDSQL

$stockName = '<the stock name>';
$numStocks = <number of stocks>;
$memberId = <member ID>;

$conn = new mysqli('hostname', 'username', 'pass', 'database if needed');
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sdi', $stockName, $numStocks, $memberId);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```